# google eclipse 3.7 plugin 2.6.0.v201205021203-rel-r37 jpa issue

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, eclipse-plugin

I am having an issue with deploying appengine. At the end of the application deployment, I get the following error

```
An internal error occurred during: "Deploying My GWT AppEngine to Google".
org/eclipse/jpt/jpa/core/JpaProject
```

The application get deployed but if I run that version, I get problem with my data get the following error log.

```
The class "The class "com.example.mygwt.engine.bean.Bean" is not persistable. 
This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version 
of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), 
or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found." is not persistable.
```

I don't have that issue before I update the google eclipse plugin.

**eclipse crash log**

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.6.0_15
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

Error
Wed May 16 13:03:13 EDT 2012
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core (295).

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.JptJpaCorePlugin for bundle org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentType.getDescriber(ContentType.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.collectMatchingByContents(ContentTypeCatalog.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.internalFindContentTypesFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.internalFindContentTypesFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.getDescriptionFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.getDescriptionFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeMatcher.getDescriptionFor(ContentTypeMatcher.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ContentDescriptionManager.readDescription(ContentDescriptionManager.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ContentDescriptionManager.getDescriptionFor(ContentDescriptionManager.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.internalGetCharset(File.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getCharset(File.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getCharset(File.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceTextFileBuffer.cacheEncodingState(ResourceTextFileBuffer.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceTextFileBuffer.initializeFileBufferContent(ResourceTextFileBuffer.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceFileBuffer.create(ResourceFileBuffer.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.TextFileBufferManager.connect(TextFileBufferManager.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.FileBufferModelManager.getModel(FileBufferModelManager.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl._doCommonGetModel(ModelManagerImpl.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl._commonGetModel(ModelManagerImpl.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl._commonGetModel(ModelManagerImpl.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl.getModelForRead(ModelManagerImpl.java:1419)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.SseUtilities.getModelForRead(SseUtilities.java:142)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.uibinder.validators.UiBinderJavaValidator$UiBinderSubtypeVisitor.parseAndValidateUiXml(UiBinderJavaValidator.java:291)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.uibinder.validators.UiBinderJavaValidator$UiBinderSubtypeVisitor.visit(UiBinderJavaValidator.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration.accept0(TypeDeclaration.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2585)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration.accept0(TypeDeclaration.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2585)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit.accept0(CompilationUnit.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.uibinder.validators.UiBinderJavaValidator.validate(UiBinderJavaValidator.java:519)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.validators.java.JavaCompilationParticipant$2.acceptAST(JavaCompilationParticipant.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnitResolver.resolve(CompilationUnitResolver.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnitResolver.resolve(CompilationUnitResolver.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createASTs(ASTParser.java:894)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.dom.ASTBatchParser.createASTs(ASTBatchParser.java:100)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.validators.java.JavaCompilationParticipant.handleBuildStarting(JavaCompilationParticipant.java:326)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.validators.java.JavaCompilationParticipant.access$0(JavaCompilationParticipant.java:307)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.validators.java.JavaCompilationParticipant$1.run(JavaCompilationParticipant.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:166)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Project facet jst.web has not been defined.
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectFrameworkImpl.getProjectFacet(FacetedProjectFrameworkImpl.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.ProjectFacetsManager.getProjectFacet(ProjectFacetsManager.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.JptJpaCorePlugin.<clinit>(JptJpaCorePlugin.java:210)
    ... 70 more
```

Comment: This probably isn't much help (hence not an answer) but I got the same error at the end of deployment, but my app's working fine. Suggests the error message you see in Eclipse might be a red herring...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a desired fix. I have downloaded the new eclipse 3.7.2 and reinstall the plugins.